# iOS:Extra space at the bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created `UITableView` programmatically, but it has some extra space below (29 pixels to be precise).

This is how I initialize the table:

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.contentView addSubview:tableView];
self.alertsTableView = tableView;
```

Here are the constraints:

```
    @"V:|-10-[_alertsTableView(0)]-5-[_optionsLabel]",
    @"H:|-15-[_alertsTableView]-15-|",
```

I tried setting the footer view to nil and returning zero for its height:

```
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]];

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

I dynamically change its height, based on the content:

```
- (void)updateHeight:(CGFloat)height {
    if (self.tableView.superview) {
        NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.tableView.superview.constraints) {
            if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                heightConstraint = constraint;
                break;
            }
        }
        heightConstraint.constant = height;
    }
}
```

I also set `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to `NO`. And [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdy9C.png) is the end result. There is a separator between the cell and the empty space, but the bottom is not a cell.

Comment: you can also set footerview using. table.tableFooterView = [uiview new];

Comment: Try the "Debug View Hierarchy" button - might help you see which UIView is taking up the space.

Comment: Can you share the code how you are calculating the `height`. Also i would recommend a change in approach how you update the constraint. Instead of running through all constraints you can have an ivar for height constraint at first place and can directly update it's value in `updateHeight:` method.

Comment: @Gandalf I just set it be equal to `contentSize.height` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. I will look into your suggestion, the problem is, that all of this happens between three different classes (the delegate methods are in a separate delegate class, the viewcontroller and a view, where the table lives, which is a subview of the viewcontroller).

Comment: You might require to setup contentInset values. Check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW14

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use contentInset to compensate the 29px extra bottom margin:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -29, 0);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try adding a `TableViewFooterView`.

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```